# How do I convert a reference to a pointer correctly?

Tags: c++

how do I convert a reference to a pointer correctly?

The code below gives me the following warning: "taking address of temporary".

```
MyClass myclass;

vector<MyClass*> myClassList;

myClassList.push_back(&myclass);

MethodThatsNeedsVectorOFMyClassPointers(myClassList);
```

Comment: Hmm, no, his code does not give that warning.

Comment: Why do you need to store a pointer rather than just using references?

Comment: this code looks ok to me unless you try to use vector after `myClass` is destroyed..

Comment: @Mat you can't make vectors of references.

Comment: There is no temporary. You may see such a warning, but the lines of code you showed us are not responsible for that.

Comment: **I liked the warning message. :-)**

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you sure that in your real code myclass is a named MyClass object and not either an anonymous object or a reference MyClass& ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your code looks like now, you shouldn't get a warning since `myclass` and `myClassList` have the same lifetime. However, if `myClassList` outlives `myclass`, you need to dynamically allocate `MyClass`:

```
vector<MyClass*> myClassList;
{
    MyClass* myclass = new MyClass; 
    myClassList.push_back(myclass);
}
```

If the following is closer to what you actually have:

```
vector<MyClass*> myClassList;
{
   MyClass myclass;
   myClassList.push_back(&myclass);
}
```

then `myclass` is destroyed at the closing `}`, and `myClassList` will contain a pointer to released memory.

Also, is `MyClass` polymorphic? Do you really need to store pointers in the vector?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  since he's getting the warning, I'm guessing that's not his actual code - see `MethodThatsNeedsVectorOFMyClassPointers`.

Comment: You guessing that "the way [the OP has] it now" the warning is correct? Fine that explains the warning. But you're also guessing that he actually needs dynamic allocation and not just `vector<MyClass>` or some other alternative.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I rephrased.

Comment: Of course, if dynamic allocation is really necessary, it would be strongly advisable to use an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>`, not an `std::vector<MyClass*>`.

Comment: If your class `is` polymorphic and you do need to store a pointer to the base class, I would recommend checking out the very intuitive `boost::ptr_vector` class... as an alternative to a vector of unique_ptrs as leftaroundabout suggested. Especially if you are not on C++ 11